# Google Places Api, Not found result as expected, want area name under cities

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I am developing an application in which I am trying to get only area/localities under the city via google places API but the API is NOT returning all the related results to the related keyword.

I am using URL:-
Google API request -> (AutoComplete places API)
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/jsonquery=Bot+in+Noida&key=Api_Key
(trying to get all area/localities names starting from "Bot" under city "Noida")

in this URL I am trying to get area names under the city named "Noida" but API shows some unwanted shop names, other irrelevant things [Image_LocalityNameResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwZJK.png).

Is there is any way to get the Area/Localities name under the city? Below are the Images to understand the project requirement.
[screen1_Image[][screen2_Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dMJ6.png)

Comment: If anyone knows the answer please sharing your solution.
"If you have knowledge, let others light their candles in it." :)